# How can i generate a 6 digit number in php?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I automatically generate a unique, random 6 digit number to insert into a column of a mysql table? The randomly generated number must not already exist in the column.

I am accessing mysql via php.

The table format is like so, with the random number going in the reqnumber column:

```
id,status,reqnumber
```

Comment: randomly generate or increment the latest existing id on the table?

Comment: Set your id as `int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY `, it will automatically increment when you insert a new row and will be unique.

Comment: if it's ID, why do you want from randomly generated number?

Comment: because i want give each customer a unique number to Follow request

Comment: Then you'd be better to leave the ID as an auto-increment index, and then use PHP's `uniqid()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   function gen(){
    $num = rand(100000,999999);
    if($num == ifnumberinyourdatabase){
    gen();
    }
    return $num;
    }
```

You can also use recursive function here.
which check's if number is your database if it is generate new one if not return the unique number

```
function gen(){
        $num = rand(100000,999999);
$query_idgetrs = "SELECT * FROM servicetbl where reqnumber = $num";
$idgetrs = mysql_query($query_idgetrs, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_num_rows($idgetrs);

        if($row >= 1){
        gen();
        }
        return $num;
        }
```

Comment: It is impossible for this to generate `000010`.

Comment: OH in that case your answer looks right, But it need to check in database

Comment: can you help me to write "ifnumberinyourdatabase" code?
$query_idgetrs = "SELECT id FROM servicetbl";
$idgetrs = mysql_query($query_idgetrs, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
while ($idgetrs1 = mysql_fetch_array($idgetrs)) {
$peyg = $idgetrs1[0];
    echo $peyg;   
}

help me to change this code

Comment: @CGoldisFakhry edited answer hope helps, use mysql_num_rows() to check how many rows are returned if `1 or more` means it's in your database so  generate `$num` again

Comment: @davidstrachan typecast it

Comment: @BasicBridge Your Answer was correct. For a 6 digit number(INT) to be stored in database it must start at 100000. If you want to store 000010 it has to be stored as a string

Comment: gen()
        }
        return $num;
        }
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in :gen() } why?

Comment: Best solution found that worked pretty fast for me. Needed to generate 14.000 unique 6 digits numbers and check them each time. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate a random number and then use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$myRandom = str_pad(rand(1,999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

The problem that you're going to run into is that since you require this to be random, there's no way to know if it exists in the table until it's generated. You'd have to make a loop and keep checking in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Put unique constraint on reqnumber field and put error handling code in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Although random is ok, please note that 6 digits only offers 1 million combinations.  I'm not sure how long it would be before you started getting duplicate primary key errors.

A much better solution would be to use a unique value.  This is very different to a random value as the unique value guarantees to by different every time.  MySql has the auto_increment datatype to help you with this.  Unfortunately, you are still limited to 1 million entries when using 6 digits.

If you want a totally random, long identifier, check out [MySql's UUID functio](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)n.  It will generate a unique string that is guaranteed to never repeat.  However it is much longer than 6 characters because that's what it can take to achieve uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

A part of your table structure must be:

```
`id` mediumint(6) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

If you really need 6 digits always:

`ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;`

or use 
`sprintf()`

Comment: This assigns a max length of 6 to the integer. It will not convert `12` to `000012`.